# Append the count of the occurrence of the word in python Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nlp

My original data

[image]

I want to convert the text data into a dataframe which will contain the 500 words like the below picture in which each sentence will contain the occurrence of that word in the particular sentence (Row of a dataframe.)

Final Output_data

[image]

I have performed text preprocessing and all with NLTK.

Comment: _Kindly help._ With what, what specifically is the issue? Please provide a [mcve], and see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: I need to create term docoment matrix of the dataframe like the above shown.

Answer (score 0):

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
count_vect = CountVectorizer()
X_train_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(twenty_train.data)
```

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/text_analytics/working_with_text_data.html

Comment: This will only form a vector martrix. But I donot want that. I want to get the occurrence of  each word in a sentence in the dataframe.